# Dynamic data calculations using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I want a sub-totals within nested repeat, think of it like a shop cart but the cart is split into products (shoes, jackets) or some other nested structure.

So I figured there are (at least) 3 different ways of achieving the same result. What is the difference, particularly with performance, and which should I use (for lots of data)?

It's worth noting this is more about data presentation (like an admin view) and isn't just a question about how to total a cart (which has been covered a lot!). More about how to handle it from a data point of view when you have lots of carts and lots of other calculations such as average cost, accumulative cost.. persons favourite color on a Tuesday (or whatever!).

### In the Template

```
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in cart.products">
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in product.items">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.cost}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <td>{{ getProductTotal(product) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>{{ getCartTotal() }}</tr>
</table>
```

### Property of the Object

```
$scope.cart = {
    person: "Nicky poppy pie",
    products: {},
    total: function () {
        var total = 0;
        foreach(product...)
        return total;
    }
};
```

or

```
$scope.cart = {};
$scope.cart.total = getCartTotal()

function getCartTotal() {
    //insert crazy calculations
}
```

### Watchers

```
$scope.$watch('cart', function() {
    var cartTotal = 0;
    $scope.cartItems.forEach(function(product) {
      cartTotal += product.cost();
    });
    $scope.cartTotal = cartTotal;
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching it the wrong way.

You should have the total as a property of your cart object. And in your view you bind it normally.
You don't want to do all your "crazy calculations" on each $scope.$digest but only once when:

- product is added (ex: cart.addProduct(product))
- product is removed (ex: cart.removeProduct(product))
- quantity has changed (ex: cart.updateQtyProduct(productId, qty))
- ...

At the end of each of theses method you call your updateTotalCart() method and set the property on the object.

Comment: What if I'm getting a history of every cart someone has bought?
When I say dynamic I don't mean I want to be adding new items to the carts (addProduct()), more, if I selected a different person and then I have to update the totals of all of their carts, products and items.
The data will be loaded up on the select but then I just need to calculate totals and averages each time.

Comment: Were does all this history come from, a database? You would then already have the total in the database, no?
If not, you probably have a 'carts' Array per user (example: user.carts = [{products:[...], datetime: ... }, {products:[...], datetime: ...}, {}, {}]. You could just loop the array and calculate the total of each cart.

The idea is to not calculate inside your view but once you load the data.

Comment: If you're suggesting rollups they aren't a good solution to this. The problem is not how to calculate totals/averages (and whatever else) its where to put the calculations in the AngularJS controller in terms of the execution (for performance and reasons explained above). Sorry if I didn't make this clear

Comment: The calculation should not be done in a Controller. It should be done in a service. Like I said in my first answer, the calculation is done when a product is added / modified or updated and that is done in a Angular service. In the controller you should only point to the calculated property on the object. Sorry I can't help you more unless you detail more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation on *angularjs expression*:

***If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view.*** [angularjs doc link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

I think this basically means that if you think that your calculations are simple enough, you CAN use angular expressions.

But if the calculations are complex, a controller method is preferable.